# Lambda with two values does not work, error: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: python, lambda, typeerror

Task is to given a list of salaries, i need to take the bonus everybody is getting as input and increase all the salaries by that amount.

Then i need to output the resulting list

So, this code works well:

```
salaries = [2000, 1800, 3100, 4400, 1500]
bonus = int(input())
salaries = list(map(lambda x: x+bonus, salaries))
print(salaries)
```

But for me to understand how its working, i change code to this one:

```
salaries = [2000, 1800, 3100, 4400, 1500]
bonus = int(input())
salaries = list(map((lambda x,y: x+y), (salaries,bonus)))
print(salaries)
```

And got a TypeError with this code

Can you guys please explain me what's wrong?

Comment: When you try to iterate over `([1,2,3],1)`, you first get `[1,2,3]` and then get `1`; you don't get `(1,1)` then `(2,1)` then `(3,1)` as you appear to hope for.

Comment: If you really want to make this work the way you have it, combining zip and the appropriate function from itertools to make a generator repeating the bonus as many times as needed could probably make that happen.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this simple syntax. This is simple and much more easy to understand. Iterate over each salary and add the bonus `[salary+bonus for salary in salaries]`

```
salaries = [2000, 1800, 3100, 4400, 1500]
bonus = int(input())
salaries = [salary+bonus for salary in salaries]
print(salaries)
```

Comment: Yes, its working, but how is understand different between 'salary' and 'salaries'?

Comment: @ArturKv `salary` is each element in `salaries`

Comment: `salaries` is the list shown on the first line with all elements while `salary` contains a single element of `salaries` during the `iteration`. You can name `salary` anything and it will still work.

Answer (score 2):

When using `map(function, iterable, *iterables)`,
every item in `iterable` is passed to the function as one argument.
**The `function` parameter of the `map` call must be a function that takes a single parameter.**
The posted code expects two (`lambda x, y: ...`), that's why you get an error.

Furthermore, the `iterable` parameter in your example is the tuple `(salaries, bonus)`,
so the lambda will be called first for `salaries`,
and then for `bonus`, separately.

It seems you're looking for this:

```
list(map(lambda x: x + bonus, salaries))
```

And a more natural way to write this is with a list comprehension,
as suggested by the other answer.

If the `iterable` parameter is a tuple of two values, then you can use index on `x` of the `lambda x: ...` to use it, for example:

```
list(map(lambda x: x[0] + x[1], zip(salaries, (bonus,) * len(salaries))))
```

Here, I built a list of `(salary, bonus)` pairs with `zip` to pass a pair of values to the lambda.